# Inter Communication for applications in local network architecture

Tags: architecture

I am looking to architect an application that will run on the local network.

What we have is:

- 'n' number of laptops connected to a local network
- All those laptops will be running that application
- If one of the application makes an API call to an external network

  - It has to inform all the other laptops running the application about this.

I want to know the optimal solution for informing other laptops part.
I am thinking to create a TCP request to inform all the laptops in the network.
Is there any other approach better approach to solve this situation?

Comment: see [Green fields, blue skies, and the white board - what is too broad?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6961/31260)

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked at [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?WT.mc_id=dotnet-35129-website&view=aspnetcore-6.0)?

> The SignalR Protocol is a protocol for two-way RPC over any Message-based transport. Either party in the connection may invoke procedures on the other party, and procedures can return zero or more results or an error.